# Word document locked for editing not able to open through Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to open word document which is restricted for editing through excel VBA but getting error

> "This method or Property is not available because the document is locked for editing"

and then again another error

> "Method run of object _application Failed"

because of this error the macro is getting stuck.

```
path_src = Range("F2").Value & "\" & Range("B" & i)

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
   
With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With
   
On Error GoTo 0

Set ObjDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(Filename)
```

Comment: This code looks like it either is malware itself, or exists for enable other malware.

Comment: In which line do you get the error? The first error means that the file is protected and cannot be edited. You need to unprotect it first. • I recommend to read [ask], [mcve] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)

Comment: Have you tried accessing `Application.HackerMode - True` mode? More details can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)

Comment: I am getting an error on the last line  - objWord.Documents.Open(Filename:=path_src)

Comment: Which error? Please be more specific.

Comment: While you are debugging, comment out the line about screen updating. You want to see what is going on. Can you open the document in the interface (i.e., not through code)?